# C - button pressed once registered twice - MSP430

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, interrupt, msp430

I wanted to create a game where a player has to repeat a random pattern of flashing lights with the keys on the MSP430. The random pattern is created with an ADC - 0 represents the red light on P1.0 blinking and 1 the green light on P4.7. 
After playing it myself I noticed that sometimes when I press a button once it is registered as pressed twice. 
For example: The pattern is red/red/red/green (0/0/0/1) then pressing the left button twice and the right button once is enough because the first push of the left button is registered as two pushes.
I reduced the code of the game to a smaller program in which it's only necessary to repeate the pattern of the example above:

```
#include <msp430.h> 

int pattern[4];
unsigned int index = 0;
unsigned int button;
unsigned int buttonPressed = 0;

void Initialize_LED(void)
{
  P4DIR = P4DIR | 0x80; 
  P4OUT &= ~0x80;
  P1DIR = P1DIR | 0x01;   
  P1OUT &=~0x01;                                                       
  pattern[0] = 0;
  pattern[1] = 0;
  pattern[2] = 0;
  pattern[3] = 1;
}  

void Initialize_Buttons(void){
  P1REN |= 0x02;                         
  P1OUT |= 0x02;                          
  P2REN |= 0x02;                          
  P2OUT |= 0x02;                          
  P1IFG &= ~0x02;                        
  P2IFG &= ~0x02;                         
  P1IE |= 0x02;                           
  P2IE |= 0x02;                           
                                      //Timer:----------------------------     
  TA1CTL = TASSEL_1+ID_0+MC_2+TACLR;  // 
  TA1R = 40000;                       // 
                                      // ----------------
  _BIS_SR(GIE);                            

}

void main(void)                                                         
{                                                               
  WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD;                                                                                                             
  Initialize_LED();   
  Initialize_Buttons();

  int done = 0;
  while(done == 0){
    if(buttonPressed == 1){
      if(pattern[index] != button){
          P1OUT ^= 0x01;
          done++;                       //wrong button --> green light on
      } else {
          index++;
          buttonPressed = 0;
          if (index == 4){
            done++;
          }
      } 
    }     
   }
    P1OUT ^= 0x01;                      // correct pattern --> both lights on
    P4OUT ^= 0x80;
}


#pragma vector=PORT1_VECTOR // ----------- Interrupt Service Routine -----------
__interrupt void Port1_Interrupt (void) {

  buttonPressed = 1;                                      
  if (P1IFG&0x02){                          
    button = 1;
    P1IE &= ~0x02;                          
    TA1CTL |= TAIE;                        
    TA1R = 50000;                           
  }                                         
}

#pragma vector=PORT2_VECTOR // ----------- Interrupt Service Routine -----------
__interrupt void Port2_Interrupt (void) {

  buttonPressed = 1;                        
  if (P2IFG&0x02){                          
    button = 0;
    P2IE &= ~0x02;                          
    TA1CTL |= TAIE;                         
    TA1R = 50000;                           
  }                                         
}

#pragma vector=TIMER1_A1_VECTOR             // Timer1_A3 Interrupt Vector(TAIV) handler
__interrupt void TIMER1_A1_ISR(void)
{
    switch (__even_in_range(TA1IV, 14))
    {
    case  0: break;                          
    case  2: break;                          
    case  4: break;                          
    case  6: break;                          
    case  8: break;                          
    case 10: break;                          
    case 12: break;                          
    case 14:                                 
                 P1IFG &= ~0x02;                
                 P1IE |= 0x02;                  
                 P2IFG &= ~0x02;                
                 P2IE |= 0x02;                  
                 TA1CTL &= ~TAIE;                
                 break;
    default: break;
    }  
}
```

I went through the code with the debugger but can't find the reason why this keeps happening. Is someone able to help me?
 Thanks for your time!

Comment: Are you sure it's not a hardware issue (insufficient debouncing)?

Comment: @Toby If insufficient debouncing is the problem is there any way to solve this?

Comment: You can do debouncing in software, for example by polling the buttons as part of a timer loop. If the timer frequency is not too high, you can record the current button state and use it as is. If the timer frequency is too high, you may need to filter out high frequency button state transitions in your code.

Comment: We don't appear to have a canonical Q+A about button debouncing.  But this answer is pretty good one for how one could do debouncing. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23557921/how-to-detect-two-or-more-button-press-gpio-at-the-same-time-by-a-microprocess/23559522#23559522

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every mechanical contact generate pulses - bounces during switch ON and also OFF. You need create an debouncing filter for this.

My proposals is for you to completely avoid interrupts for reading status of buttons.

Best way to debounce buttons by SW is to sample it with sampling time longer than button generate bounce pulses (it is generally about 1-10ms).

You can do it by reading actual status of buttons every 10ms and compare it with previous status. Then you will have completely debounced button(s).

I use this method in many projects, where I don't need HW filter and same principle is used for example in any PC keyboard, where HW filter is not possible to add, because all the buttons are multiplexed, but this is better to discus on https://electronics.stackexchange.com